# FATAL datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain

Tags: hadoop

I'm very new in Hadoop. After following manual http://toodey.com/2015/08/10/hadoop-installation-on-windows-without-cygwin-in-10-mints/ and run my hadoop i got 3 errors:

**1) FATAL datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while running command to get file permissions : ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:**

**2) FATAL nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)**

**3)ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z**

I googled many hours but unfortunately no results.

What can be wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Inslalled ubuntu instead of Windows

Comment: Not a solution.